# Why can I just change count and update it in the child component?

Tags: vuejs3

Why can I just change count and update it in the child component?

```
<script setup>
defineProps(['count'])

</script>
<template>
  <p>Child</p>
  <p> props：{{ count }}</p>
  <button @click="count++">+</button> `why can i modify`
  <button @click="count--">-</button> `why can i modify`
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the console in your browser you should have some warnings there like this:

```
[Vue warn] Set operation on key "count" failed: target is readonly.[object Object]
```

You have to avoid mutations props from child components. Instead you can define emit

```
const emit = defineEmits(["on-count-changed"]);
```

and call the emit in your click func:

```
<button @click="emit('on-count-changed', count + 1)">+</button>
```

Then you can catch this event in your parent component. Please see code below:

**Parent.vue**

```
<script setup>
    import Child from "./Child.vue";
  import { ref } from "vue";
  
  const count = ref(0);
  const onCountChanged = (value) => {
    count.value = value;
  };
</script>
<template>
  <Child :count="count" @on-count-changed="onCountChanged"></Child>
</template>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<script setup>
    defineProps(['count'])
    const emit = defineEmits(["on-count-changed"])
</script>
<template>
  <p>Child</p>
  <p> props：{{ count }}</p>
  <button @click="emit('on-count-changed', count + 1)">+</button> `why can i modify`
  <button @click="emit('on-count-changed', count - 1)">-</button> `why can i modify`
</template>
```

You can read about this more here - https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use props properly, but there will be no warning on the console and the data in the child component will be updated normally. This is like redeclaring the ref result with count alone in the child component, and it won't affect the change of count in the parent component